# the window won't respond when I attempt to create a thresholded image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

when I attempt to run the code, the window that is meant to display the thresholded image won't respond.

```
import cv2 

src = cv2.imread("C:/Users/MikePC/Pictures/LifeCam Files/2017-07-14 12-20-
19.930.jpg",0)

thresh = 255
maxValue = 0

th, dst = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow( "thickerblackwaveblackaxis.PNG", dst)

cv2.imwrite("thickerblackwaveblackaxis.PNG", dst)
```

Comment: [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) without [`waitKey`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey). Read the docs: "This function should be followed by waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image." | `imread` can fail to read the image -- test the result before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your threshold value is 255 and maxValue is 0 which means you will encounter completely black image (check opencv threshold documentation), you should change these values as I do in my code below. Other than that, I recommend you to use double slashes "`\\`" when working on Windows platform since single slash is used for special character(such as cases `\n` `\t` etc.) and always check if your image contains any data before processing:

```
import cv2 

src = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\MikePC\\Pictures\\LifeCam Files\\2017-07-14 12-20-19.930.jpg",0)

maxValue = 255
thresh= 0

if not src is None
    th, dst = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imshow( "thickerblackwaveblackaxis.PNG", dst)
    cv2.imwrite("thickerblackwaveblackaxis.PNG", dst)
    cv2.waitKey(0) #it keeps the windows open forever
else
    print 'Image could not be read'
```

As OpenCV documentation states that: The function waitKey(delay) waits for a key event infinitely when delay <= 0 or for delay milliseconds, when it is positive. Therefore, this code will keep the image window open until you press any key.

Comment: Paths with forward slashes work just fine on Windows, you can easily verify that. Suggesting to test the result of `imread` is useful. However, just as the OP, you're missing the crucial `waitKey`. Hence, this code is as dysfunctional as the original.

Comment: Yes you are right waitKey is the problem. I have experienced problems with single slashes and never used them again(at least for C++), it may result in empty images. Also I edited my answer

Comment: That's a step in a good direction. I would suggest few more improvements: 1) Add some explanation about the slashes to the answer. 2) Add references to the docs, along with quoting the important bits (sort of like I have in my comment to the question).

Comment: I did it and I found another mistake about calling threshold lol.

Comment: @Bhoke could you please tell me the other mistake you found about  calling threshold, because Im getting a plain black Image now as opposed to a white wave with a black background. I know I must seem quite stupid but this is my first week learning any sort of coding or programming

Comment: @Bhoke I know you mentioned it above but could you give me an indication to which values I should change it to instead

Comment: You should set maxValue to 255 to distinct the image as black & white. and appropriate threshold value is about 127(It sets the pixels above127 to 0 and sets te pixels below 127 to 255 for THRESH_BINARY_INV flag). You should see the official documentation before implementation http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold.